# Determining when two binary strings represent the same necklace or when one binary string is periodic

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorics-on-words, necklace-and-bracelets

An equivalence relation on binary strings calls two strings equivalent if one can be obtained from the other by a cyclic permutation of the characters.  Combinatorialists call the equivalence classes of such strings "necklaces".

Given two binary strings of length $n$, the brute-force method for determining if they are equivalent is just iteratively cycling one of them $n$ times and comparing to see if the other string is ever obtained.  Is there a faster algorithm?  Perhaps there is a list of invariants that are fast to compute and uniquely determine the necklace?  Or perhaps through a bijection with some other set, like the irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_2$ with degree dividing $n$, it is possible to more efficiently solve the problem and transfer back?

A related question: is there an algorithm better than iterative cycling and comparison to get a computer to recognize if a string is periodic?  That is, is there a fast algorithm to compute the stabilizer subgroup of a string under the action of the cyclic group of order $n$?

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to you could get worst-case $O(n\log n)$ using a fast fourier transform, at least when $n$ is a power of $2$.

I know nothing about such things, but I doubt that this could be worth the trouble, because it seems to me that the brute-force approach is going to be $O(n)$ on average. Because you can compare two random strings of arbitrary length in constant average time:

The probability you get a "no" after looking at the first character is $1/2$. The probability that you have to look at the first and then the second characters to get a "no" is $1/4$. And so on; the expected value of the number of character comparisons needed is no larger than $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k 2^{-k}<\infty.$$

Comment: This right when you look at an individual comparison. If you have lots of necklaces and want to compare them pairwise, it may pay off to perform $O(n)$ or $O(n\log n)$ precomputation operations per necklace and then only require $O(1)$ operations per comparison. The FFT might be a good candidate here, since it combines complete information with good differentiation already for a single comparison. It would also immediately tell you whether a sequence is periodic.